# Use Jest fake timers for all tests

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I would like to run all the tests in my project with fake timers.

I am looking for a way to define it once for all instead put `jest.useFakeTimers()` into each test file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update the answer written by `Ivan Surzhenko`.

For jest v29, you can config it as the screenshot. Here is the doc link: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#faketimers-object

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Looks like I have found.

Just put the following to jest config:
`"timers": "fake",`

Comment: just in case link to relevant place in docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#timers-string

Comment: @skyboyer Yeah. It is a perfect link. Could you please add it as an answer?. So, I will choose your one.

Comment: better just include that into your answer so it'd be more visible for anyone